# A javascript function that works in the head, but not as source file

Tags: javascript, html, function, src, onsubmit

I have a javascript function to validate a form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formValidate()
        {
            // create array containing textbox elements
            var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('lname'), document.getElementById('email1'), document.getElementById('email2'), document.getElementById('message')];

            var error;

            for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
            // loop through each element to see if value is empty
            {
                if(inputs[i].value == '')
                {
                    error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                    alert(error);
                    return false;
                    }
            }
         }
</script>
```

It works when in the head of the html page, but not when I reference it from another file.

```
<script src="form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

form code:

```
<form onsubmit="return formValidate()"  action="mailto:admin@sfasc.com.au" method="post"  id="contactForm" >
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content returned for the `<script>` tag should be **only** your JavaScript, and not include any HTML. That means your JS file should only include JS code and not the `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` parts. Your HTML file takes care of HTML, which is why you have `<script src="form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.